# How to get process id from output of ps -ef | grep 'tomcat'?

Tags: linux, tomcat

I want to kill tomcat process and hence used command -

```
ps -ef | grep 'tomcat'
```

and it returns following big output and there I can see 3 pids -

```
oracle    76220 218600  3 May16 pts/2    00:40:14 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -DcoreJMX=true -DqueryJMX=true -javaagent:/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco141.exec,append=false,includes=com.eqtechnologic.* -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/logs/gcLogs.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -classpath /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Dcatalina.home=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
oracle   138680 219157  0 15:46 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
oracle   187823 161915  1 May16 pts/1    00:29:01 //bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -DcoreJMX=true -DqueryJMX=true -javaagent:/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco141.exec,append=false,includes=com.eqtechnologic.* -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/logs/gcLogs.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -classpath /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Dcatalina.home=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

But I am confused which one is pid of tomcat. Can someone please help me to understand how to read this output which will help me to get pid of tomcat?

If I guessed correctly, is `138680` pid of tomcat?

Comment: No, that's the PID of your `grep` command. Doesn't Tomcat have a special `shutdown.sh` script?

Comment: Actually I have Jacoco (Java code coverage tool) integrated and it generates report in `jacoco.exec` file when application is turned down. But when I run `shutdown.sh`, it does not generate report hence it's not helping. If I use `CTRL+C`, for running application(which is run using `catalina..sh run`). To invoke behaviour like `CTRL+C` through shell script, I'm trying to use `kill -SIGINT processPIDHere` hence want to get pid.

Answer (score 1):

Like Kusalananda said in the comment, Tomcat has a `shutdown.sh` script in the bin folder. Anyway, if for some reason you want to kill it with the `kill` command, there is the `pidof` command that gives you the pid of a running program.

Comment: Also `pkill`, which would be more direct, but their issue seems to be figuring out how to select the right process. Using the `shutdown.sh` script would be the best alternative as that script probably shots down the service in a more orderly manner.

Comment: `pkill -9 -f tomcat` is also not helping me to achieve what I mentioned in comment to question.

Comment: @TDHM Did you try with the `INT` signal in place of the `KILL` signal?

Comment: I am getting `INT command not found`. I'm newbie to linux environment. Can you please help with exact command?